# How to delete files older than 30 days based on the date in the filename

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have CSV files get updated every day and we process the files and delete the files older than 30 days based on the date in the filename. 
Example filenames :

`XXXXXXXXXXX_xx00xx_**20171001**.000000_0.csv`

I would like to schedule the job in crontab to delete 30 days older files daily.

Path could be `/mount/store/
XXXXXXXXXXX_xx00xx_**20171001**.000000_0.csv`

```
if [ $(date -d '-30 days' +%Y%m%d) -gt $D ]; then
    rm -rf $D
fi
```

this above script doesn't seem to help me. Kindly help me on this. 
I have been trying this for last two days.

Using CENTOS7

Thanks.

Comment: *Path could be* or could it be in other format?

Comment: Path is /mount/store.

Comment: I don't have CentOS, does it have gnu-find? Has it cdate and mdate and is one of them in sync with the date in the name?

Answer (score 0):

For all files:

- Extract the date
- touch the file with that date
- delete files with the -mtime option

Do this in the desired dir for all files:

```
f=XXXXXXXXXXX_xx00xx_20171001.000000_0.csv
d=$(echo $f | sed -r 's/[^_]+_[^_]+_(20[0-9]{6})\.[0-9]{6}_.\.csv/\1/')
touch -d $d $f
```

After performing that for the whole dir, delete the older-thans:

```
find YourDir -type f -mtime +30 -name "*.csv" -delete
```

Gnu-sed has the -delete option. Other finds might need -exec rm ... .

Test before. Other pitfalls are different kind of dates, affected by touch (mtime, ctime, atime).

Test, manipulating the date with touch:

```
touch XXXXXXXXXXX_xx00xx_20171001.000000_0.csv
f=XXXXXXXXXXX_xx00xx_20171001.000000_0.csv; d=$(echo $f | sed -r 's/[^_]+_[^_]+_(20[0-9]{6})\.[0-9]{6}_.\.csv/\1/'); touch -d $d $f 
ls -l $f
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stefan stefan 0 Okt  1 00:00 XXXXXXXXXXX_xx00xx_20171001.000000_0.csv
```

Comment: in this file name XXXXXXXXXXX_xx00xx_20171001.000000_0.csv could be any random characters.XXXX= random characters, 0000= random numbers

Comment: We can only work with the informations you give us. "Any random characters" would include additional string parts, matching dates. If you don't give information, how to find the date in discussion, we have to guess. Beside from this is this not a `get a coder for free` service, so try it out and fix the expression for your needs. It shall be a help, not a ready made solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help User. however, Please try to understand , I'm very basic beginner for this. I have my own expertise contributing to the different community on my expertise. Live let live is my policy . Be cool . Thanks for all the help . Cheers:)

Comment: Changing the date with `touch` destroys information of the file. I would not advise this approach.

Comment: @kvantour: I would say that a potential user should know himself, whether the information needs to be preserved or not.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way to extract date from filename is to use variable expansions

```
f=XXXXXXXXXXX_xx00xx_20171001.000000_0.csv
d=${f%%.*}    # removes largest suffix .*
d=${d##*_}    # removes largest prefix *_
```

Or to use bash specific regex

```
if [[ $f =~ [0-9]{8} ]]; then echo "$BASH_REMATCH"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if you have `dgrep` from [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/).

```
ls *.csv | dateutils.dgrep -i '%Y%m%d' --le $(date -d "-30 day" +%F) | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

First we can use either `ls` or `find` to obtain a list of filenames. We can then pipe the results to `dgrep` to filter the filenames that contains a date string which matches our condition (in this case older than 30 days). Finally, we pipe the result to `xargs rm` to remove all the matched files.

- `-i '%Y%m%d'` input date format as specified in your filename
- `--le $(date -d "-30 day" +%F)` filter dates that are older than 30 days

You can change `rm` to `printf "%s\n"` to test the command before actually deleting it.

Comment: You [should not use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Try `printf '%s\n' *.csv` (this still assumes none of your file names has a newline in its name).

Answer (score 0):

The following approach does not look at any generation time information of the file, it assumes the date in the filename is unrelated to the day the file is created.

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
d=$(date -d "-30 days" "+%Y%m%d")
for file in /yourdir/*csv; do
     date=${file:$((${#file}-21)):8}
     (( date < d )) && rm $file
done
```