# Delete all files older than 30 days, based on file name as date

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new to bash, I have a task to delete all files older than 30 days, I can figure this out based on the files name `Y_M_D.ext` `2019_04_30.txt`.

I know I can list all files with `ls` in a the folder containing the files. I know I can get todays date with `$ date` and can configure that to match the file format `$ date "+%Y_%m_%d"`

I know I can delete files using `rm`.

How do I tie all this together into a bash script that deletes files older than 30 days from today?

In pseudo-python code I guess it would look like:

```
for file in folder:
    if file.name to date > 30 day from now:
        delete file
```

Comment: First step is to convert the string "YYYY_MM_DD.txt" to an epoch time.  Do not bother attempting to compare dates until you have an epoch time.

Comment: `date --date "2019/04/30" +"%s"` and `date +"%s"` give you the timestamp for the given date and today, you merely need to transform the filename and then compare the stamps

Comment: The duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294284/how-to-delete-files-older-than-30-days-based-on-the-date-in-the-filename?rq=1&noredirect=1 has several additional solutions, though none of them are upvoted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am by no means a systems administrator, but you could consider a simple shell script along the lines of:

```
# Generate the date in the proper format
discriminant=$(date -d "30 days ago" "+%Y_%m_%d")

# Find files based on the filename pattern and test against the date.
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "*_*_*.txt" -printf "%P\n" |
while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    if [ "${discriminant}" ">" "${FILE%.*}" ]; then
        echo "${FILE}";
    fi
done
```

Note that this is will probably be considered a "layman" solution by a professional. Maybe this is handled better by `awk`, which I am unfortunately not accustomed to using.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution to delete log files older than 30 days:

```
#!/bin/sh

# A table that contains the path of directories to clean
rep_log=("/etc/var/log" "/test/nginx/log")
echo "Cleaning logs - $(date)."

#loop for each path provided by rep_log 
for element in "${rep_log[@]}"
do
   #display the directory
    echo "$element";
    nb_log=$(find "$element" -type f -mtime +30 -name "*.log*"| wc -l)
    if [[ $nb_log != 0 ]] 
    then
            find "$element" -type f -mtime +30 -delete 
            echo "Successfull!"
    else
            echo "No log to clean !"
    fi
done
```

allows to include multiple directory where to delete files

```
rep_log=("/etc/var/log" "/test/nginx/log")
```

we fill the var: we'r doing a search (in the directory provided) for files which are older than 30 days and whose name contains at least .log. Then counts the number of files.

```
nb_log=$(find "$element" -type f -mtime +30 -name "*.log*"| wc -l)
```

we then check if there is a result other than 0 (posisitive), if yes we delete

```
find "$element" -type f -mtime +30 -delete
```

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is an English forum. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55921496/edit) your answer to translate it to English (une réponse en français est hors sujet ici)

Comment: Yes sorry, i didnt notify that i was responding in french.

Answer (score 0):

For delete file older than X days you can use this command and schedule it in `/etc/crontab`

`find /PATH/TO/LOG/* -mtime +10 | xargs -d '\n' rm`

or

`find /PATH/TO/LOG/* -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm -f {} \`

Comment: FYI: Your answer is about deleting files based on their modification date, whereas the question is about deleting files based on their filename interpreted as date.