# Removing files older than X days using a date format in the filename

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a directory that includes log files, that includes the following date format (YYYY-MM-DD) in the filename.

```
app-2020-12-17.log.2
app-2020-12-18.log.1
app-2020-12-18.log.2
app-2020-12-18.log.31
app-2020-12-18.log.32
app-2020-12-18.log.33
app-2020-12-18.log.3.gz
app-2020-12-20.log.4.gz
app-2020-12-20.log.5
```

My goal is to remove all files older than X date (using the date in the filename as comparison). For example, I want to remove all files older than 2020-12-20, so after the operation I should be left with the following files in my folder:

```
app-2020-12-20.log.4.gz
app-2020-12-20.log.5
```

How can I achieve this behavior? I have tried using somethine like this `find app*log* -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1`, but this only finds files by modification date, and not the way I need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all files older than 30 days, based on file name as date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919214/delete-all-files-older-than-30-days-based-on-file-name-as-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash` and a regex:

```
for i in app-*.log*; do
  [[ "$i" =~ -([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) ]] \
    && [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" < "2020-12-20" ]] \
    && echo rm -v "$i"
done
```

`${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` contains `2020-12-17`, e.g.

As one line:

```
for i in app-*.log*; do [[ "$i" =~ -([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) ]] && [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" < "2020-12-20" ]] && echo rm -v "$i"; done
```

Output:

```
rm -v app-2020-12-17.log.2
rm -v app-2020-12-18.log.1
rm -v app-2020-12-18.log.2
rm -v app-2020-12-18.log.31
rm -v app-2020-12-18.log.32
rm -v app-2020-12-18.log.33
rm -v app-2020-12-18.log.3.gz
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, exactly the way I needed and I learned something new, thank you!